# Ubuntu 20.04 is not logging in

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

My Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 version is not logging in and it is showing the following error message:

```
WARNING: PV /dev/sda7 in VG Volgroup is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
/dev/mapper/Volgroup-lv_root: clean, 459191/3276800 files, 12464669/13107200 blo
```

Please help me.